# Values in the sorted array are completely different from the ones that were generated in the array before the sorting

Tags: vb.net

I made an array and assigned random values to it so that I could try insertion sorting on them. I first output the array that isn't sorted and then, after calling the insertion sort procedure, the sorted array. The problem is that the values in the sorted array are completely different from the ones that were generated in the array before the sorting.

Here is the output:

```
Array generated

Index No.172
Index No.263
Index No.341
Index No.481
Index No.562
Index No.644
Index No.771
Index No.891
Index No.958
Index No.1057
Index No.1133
Index No.126
Index No.1359
Index No.142
Index No.1526
Index No.1653
Index No.1718
Index No.1851
Index No.1924
Index No.2032

Array sorted

Index No.12
Index No.26
Index No.318
Index No.424
Index No.526
Index No.632
Index No.733
Index No.841
Index No.944
Index No.1051
Index No.1153
Index No.1257
Index No.1358
Index No.1459
Index No.1562
Index No.1663
Index No.1771
Index No.1872
Index No.1981
Index No.2091
```

I have no idea why it is happening. Here is my code:

```
Module Program
    Sub Main()
        Dim Array(20) As Integer
        Call GenerateValues(Array)
        Console.WriteLine("Array generated")
        Console.WriteLine("")
        Call Output(Array)
        Console.WriteLine("")
        Console.WriteLine("Array sorted")
        Console.WriteLine("")
        Call InsertionSort(Array)
        Call Output(Array)
        Console.ReadKey()
    End Sub

    Sub GenerateValues(ByVal Array() As Integer)
        Dim rand As Integer
        Dim isDuplicate As Boolean
        Dim Index As Integer = 1
        Do
            Randomize()
            rand = Int(Rnd() * 100) + 1
            isDuplicate = False
            For x = 1 To 20
                If Array(x) = rand Then
                    isDuplicate = True
                End If
            Next
            If isDuplicate = False Then
                Array(Index) = rand
                Index += 1
            End If
        Loop Until Index > 20
    End Sub
    Sub Output(ByVal Array() As Integer)
        For i = 1 To 20
            Console.WriteLine("Index No." & i & Array(i))
        Next
    End Sub
    Sub InsertionSort(ByRef Array() As Integer)
        Dim Key As Integer
        Dim Checkindex As Integer
        For i = 2 To 20
            Key = Array(i)
            Checkindex = i - 1
            While Key < Array(Checkindex) And Checkindex > 0
                Array(Checkindex + 1) = Array(Checkindex)
                Checkindex = Checkindex - 1
            End While
            Array(Checkindex + 1) = Key
        Next
    End Sub
End Module
```

Comment: You have `Console.WriteLine("Index No." & i & Array(i))`, so you have the actual value plus the iterator, which changes the *visual value* in the sorted array. Keep in mind what's in the previous comment, use the `Random` class instead of `Randomize()` (which is in the worng place) + `Rnd()` and beware of reference types passed `ByRef`

Comment: @DaveDoknjas I think for the single-range declaration of an array, it still uses the legacy VB behavior of declaring the upper bound rather than the number of elements.  I prefer to use the `To` form of declaration to remove any ambiguity (due to IMO a poor design decision in the long ago past, the lower bound can no longer be anything but zero though there are still ways to force multi-dimensional arrays to have non-zero lower bounds).  In any event, the ultimate effect is an unused entry at index 0.

Comment: @Jimi I don't see anything in the code that would make the accessor alter the array.  It writes out `Array(i)`, that doesn't change the contents of `Array`.

Comment: Have you tried debugging the insertion sort to make sure it's doing what you expect it to do?  It should be trivial to put a watch on the array and watch the contents changing.

Comment: @Craig It doesn't write out `Array(i)`, it writes `"Index No." & i & Array(i)` (iterator + value glued together), in both cases, with different values. You can also eyeball it :) --  The `ByRef` thing is a general warning

Comment: @Jimi So the real point here is to make sure what is printed is parsed correctly by the reader.

Comment: Try putting a space between the index and the value, and I think you'll find that it has what you want.  e.g. `Console.WriteLine($"Index {i} has value {Array(i)}")`.

Comment: Basically, if you had debugged the code then you would have seen what was happening for yourself and you should NEVER be posting a question here without having debugged first anyway. If you don't know how to debug, stop what you're doing and learn that first.

Comment: Won't fix the issues, but arrays are **already reference types**, even when they hold value-type members, so you don't have to pass the array `ByRef` to the sort method. Also, the `Call` keyword serves **no purpose at all** in VB.Net. It still exists solely as a hold-over from the VB6/VBScript era, to make porting in old code easier. There's no good reason at all to ever use it in new code.

Comment: @JoelCoehoorn, OT, the one use I have found for `Call` is when you want to create a new object and call a method on it without assigning it to a variable, e.g. `New SomeType().SomeMethod()`. Not something that happens often but, in that case, you cannot start a line with `New`. By adding `Call`, i.e. `Call New SomeType().SomeMethod()`, you can keep the code succinct rather than breaking it into multiple lines. I think I may have done that twice in over 20 years. Not found any other use for `Call` though.

Comment: @jmcilhinney You can also do it with parentheses: `(New SomeType()).SomeMethod()`

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is only that your ouput has missing a space

change the outout to something like this

```
Sub Output(ByVal Array() As Integer)
    For i = 1 To 20
        Console.WriteLine("Index No." & i & " " & Array(i))
    Next
End Sub
```

But your sorting can be solved by using

```
Sub InsertionSort(ByRef Array1() As Integer)
    Array.Sort(Array1)
End Sub
```

[image: sorted lists]

Comment: Correct on the spacing issue (+1), but I feel like manually implementing the insertion sort was the whole point of the project, and if I were going to suggest an alternative I'd take the opportunity to also remove the unneeded `ByRef`.

Answer (score 0):

Some of this code just cried out for modernization, so here you go. It fixes the main issue of spacing between the index and the value, and also fixed some errors around indexes (in .Net, indexes start at 0, not 1!):

```
Public Module Module1
    Sub Main()
        Dim Array() As Integer = GenerateValues(20)

        Console.WriteLine($"Array generated{vbCrLf}")
        Output(Array)

        InsertionSort(Array)
        Console.WriteLine($"Array sorted{vbCrLf}")  
        Output(Array)
        
        Console.ReadKey(True)
    End Sub

    Private rnd As New Random()
    
    Function GenerateValues(Count As Integer) As Integer()
        Dim keys As New HashSet(Of Integer)()
        While keys.Count < Count 
           keys.Add(rnd.Next(100))
        End While
        Return keys.ToArray()
    End Function

    ' The other efficient way to do this is to generate the numbers once up front, then **shuffle** the sequence to take the first 20.  
    Function GenerateValuesAlt(Count As Integer) As Integer()
        Static corpus() As Integer = Enumerable.Range(0, 100).ToArray()
        For i = 0 To Count - 1
            dim idx = rnd.Next(i, corpus.Length)
            Dim cur = corpus(i)
            corpus(i) = corpus(idx)
            corpus(idx) = cur
        Next
        Dim result(Count-1) As Integer
        Array.Copy(corpus, 0, result, 0, Count)
        Return result
    End Function

    Sub Output(items As IEnumerable(Of Integer))
        Dim idx As Integer = 0
        For Each item As Integer In items
            Console.WriteLine($"Index No. {idx+1} -- {item}")
            idx+=1
        Next
        Console.WriteLine()
    End Sub

    Sub InsertionSort(Array() As Integer)
        For i = 1 To Array.Length - 1
            Dim Key As Integer = Array(i)
            Dim Checkindex As Integer = i - 1
            While  Checkindex >= 0 AndAlso Key < Array(Checkindex) 
                Array(Checkindex + 1) = Array(Checkindex)
                Checkindex = Checkindex - 1
            End While
            Array(Checkindex + 1) = Key
        Next
    End Sub
End Module
```

> https://dotnetfiddle.net/FX203n

Answer (score 0):

Another method

```
    Static PRNG As New Random
    Dim ints() As Integer
    'some random numbers
    ints = Enumerable.Range(1001, 25).OrderBy(Function(x) PRNG.Next).ToArray
    ints = ints.Distinct.ToArray 'remove dups
    OutArray(ints) ' before
    'insertion sort
    For i As Integer = 1 To ints.Length - 1
        Dim j As Integer = i
        While j > 0 AndAlso ints(j - 1) > ints(j)
            Dim hold As Integer = ints(j)
            ints(j) = ints(j - 1)
            ints(j - 1) = hold
            j -= 1
        End While
    Next
    OutArray(ints) ' after
```

And the output method

```
Private Sub OutArray(a As Integer())
    Debug.WriteLine("-")
    For x As Integer = 0 To a.Length - 1
        Debug.WriteLine("Index: {0}  Val: {1}", x, a(x))
    Next
End Sub
```

Comment: The OP doesn't want to allow duplicates

Comment: @JoelCoehoorn - the method I used to generate test data doesn't create dups.  I just added the line needed to fix that, just in case.